# Installing directx 7 in wine on fedora

Tags: fedora, wine, winetricks

I have a very old bit of software I want to run through wine and on the system requirements it has listed DirectX 7. I attempted to install this with winetricks but the oldest version listed is directx 9. There also doesn't seem to be any up to date info online about installing DirectX 7 (Understandable since it came out in 1999)

Is there any way I can get directx 7 running in wine?

Comment: Does the software requires that DirectX version specifically? Have you tried already with DirectX 9? Maybe it works. If not that means the software you're trying to use is sooooo old you'd be much better looking for other solutions, preferably native.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia It doesn't run with dx9 but I don't know if that is the reason or if something else is going wrong. It's a game so I can't use an alternative.

Comment: DirectX should be backwards compatible, however, I have seen issues due to a variety of issues. What about using a Windows VM?

Comment: Nice suggestion @Keltari. Such old game should work fine in a VM, unlike most modern ones. But it probably has to be Windows98 for compatibility. If you do that please do not allow your VM to connect to the internet, keep it isolated and keep a snapshot backup just in case.